RS485 isolated pcb
I am working on a rs485 isolated pcb using 2 ic for iso
Adum ADUM3201 both side in 5dc and B0505S-1W both side in 5dc
I have a question about the mcu side esp32 tx and rx logic  has it's working on 3.3 volt
Do i have to put a level shifter 3.3 dc to 5dc from esp32 tx and rx uart to connect on the adum3201 ?

Schematic please?

What do the data sheets tell you?

You can't connect 5V signals from ADUM to ESP32.
And ADUM does not officially understand 3.3V signals when supplied with 5V.
Either you need logic level translation, or let the ADUM do it for you by using 3.3V supply on the ESP side.
As a side note, you may need more than just a single ADUM as you may want to control RS-485 transmit enable too for half-duplex operation, in addition to receiving and transmitting data.

The easy solution might be to change to a RS485 transceiver with 3.3V supply. Then they can supply the primary of the isolator with 3.3V as well.

Thanks for your comment
Here is the comment of the data sheet official
The ADuM3200 / ADuM3201 isolators provide two independent isolation channels in a variety of channel configurations and data rates (see the Ordering Guide). They operate with 3.3 V or 5 V supply voltages on either side, providing compatibility with lower voltage systems as well as enabling voltage translation functionality across the isolation barrier. The ADuM3200W and ADuM3201W are automotive grade versions qualified for 125°C operation.

@KhalesNaim Yes it reads that. Why quote it here? Do you have a question about it?

you will need ADuM3301 or equivalent as 3 channels (2 up 1 down)  are needed to control and use an RS485 tranciver
Power the ESP side of the coupler from the 3.3V of the ESP32

Whether or not you will need 3 channel depends on how the transmit enable is controlled. Sometimes people want automatic transmit enable circuit. Sometimes you enable the transmitter with data, for a CAN-alike recessive and dominant states.

Yes I agree with you justme I have integrate 74hc14 to manage the automatic transmit
